Identify this movie about traveler in a desert world
Recently, I saw a movie clip displayed in front of an electronics store (I was in my car, caught in a traffic jam). In the clip there is a traveler walking in the middle of the road. He has guns and wear sunglasses and worn-out clothes. The traveler has black skin and a bald head. He's also expert with a knife/sword.  
The movie takes place in a desert world. There are sandstorms and intense weird sunlight/heat. When the traveler is in a junkyard(sort of), there are people who trap him, with a woman as bait. Then, when the people attack him, he beats them with his sword.
That's all I saw in the clip. The movie is in color. Not an old style. Maybe of the year 2000's or later. I don't know the language of this movie. But it was sub-titled to my language (probably an English language movie).

The Book of Eli (2010) starring Denzel Washington as Eli. This is the scene you describe where there are people using a woman as bait prior to attacking Eli:


 

Yup. this is the scene I once saw. Thank you.
